# Double tap in an activity extends view

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i'm working on android app for painting and i want when i do double tap a bitmap appear in the view. here i do some debug but i don't know why it's not working.

Actually this class implements another class TouchEventView which contain Touchevent and motion event.

i have tried also implements double tap in the other class but it's not working as well

```
public class PlotActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener,GestureDetector.OnGestureListener{

private TouchEventView tev;
private TextView message;
private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetector;
public static final String DEBUGTAG="JWP";
Button enreg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_plot);
    tev = (TouchEventView) findViewById(R.id.canva);
    this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this);
    gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);

}

public void clearCanvas(View v){
    tev.clearCanvas();
}
public void enregInfo(View v){
    tev.savetofile();
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    Log.i(DEBUGTAG, "onLongPress: " );
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    this.gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    Log.i(DEBUGTAG, "onLongPress: " );
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    Log.i(DEBUGTAG, "onLongPress: " );
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: "It's not working"  What isn't working?  Is it crashing?  Not detecting the dobule tap?  Detecting the double tap when it didn't happen?  Something else entirely?  You need to be more precise in your problem

Comment: it not detect the double tap

Comment: Well one major problem is that you seem to think Activities have touches.  They don't.  Views get touches, not Activities.

Comment: I also implemented gestures in a view class , & it didn't work as well